# Python ValueError: I/O operation on closed file. when returning a dict from a DictReader

Tags: python

I am getting ValueError: I/O operation on closed file when I return a dict from a csv file.  How should I do this?

```
def main():
    groups = get_groups()
    for line in groups:
        print(line)

def get_groups():
    file1 = 'groups.csv'
    with open(file1, 'r') as file:
        groups = csv.DictReader(file)
    return groups
```

Comment: This is happening because the `DictReader` `groups` isn't a memory copy of the whole file. It only retrieves a fresh `dict` from the file when you iterate over it. When your code closes the scope of the `with`, the context manager closes the file. But `DictReader` needs it to be open so that it can retrieve the data from it.

Answer (score 0):

You could return a list

```
def get_groups():
    file1 = 'groups.csv'
    with open(file1, 'r') as file:
        groups = csv.DictReader(file)
        return list(groups)
```

Or keep the file opened in main()

```
def main():
    f = open('groups.csv')
    groups = get_groups(f)
    # Do your work
    f.close()

def get_groups(f):
    return csv.DictReader(f)
```